# Exported excel showing non-recognised characters in iphone

Tags: ios, iphone, excel, model-view-controller

i have this code that converts data

```
            using (XLWorkbook wb = new XLWorkbook())
            {
                wb.Worksheets.Add(dt);



                wb.Style.Alignment.Horizontal = XLAlignmentHorizontalValues.Center;

                wb.Style.Font.Bold = true;
                //string strpath = Server.MapPath("~/SavedFolder/hello.xlsx");

                //wb.SaveAs(strpath);
                HttpContext.Response.Clear();
                HttpContext.Response.Buffer = true;
                HttpContext.Response.Charset = "";
                HttpContext.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
                //HttpContext.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
                HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename= ResultReport.xls");


                using (MemoryStream MyMemoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    wb.SaveAs(MyMemoryStream);
                    MyMemoryStream.WriteTo(HttpContext.Response.OutputStream);
                    HttpContext.Response.Flush();
                    HttpContext.Response.End();

                }
```

Works fine on pc but on iphone or ipad it shows error unable to read.

So What i did ,convert the content type to CSV format,
then the excel was opening but data shown is not English its gibberish .

I tried opening excel using free apps for iphone to open documents same result
 can someone help.